# Solving a system of equations with 3 variables and only 2 given lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the augmented matrix

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 &3 &4 &7 \\ 3 &9& 7 &6\end{matrix}\right)$$

I multiplied $R_1$ by $3$ and subtracted $R_2$ leaving me with 
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 &3 &4 &7 \\ 0 &0& 5 &15\end{matrix}\right)$$

But I don't know where to go from here, $X_3 = 3$, but how do I then solve for both $X_1$ and $X_2$ with only one variable left?

Answer (score 0):

The real meaning of the second version of the augmented matrix is

$$x_1+3x_2=-5.$$
(Besides, we know that $x_3=3.$)
This is one equation with two unknowns. So one of the unknowns, say $x_1$, has to be taken as a parameter. Let then $x_1=u$. Now

$$3x_2=-5-u.$$

From here

$$x_1=u; \ x_2=-\frac{5+u}3; \ x_3=3.$$

For example, if $u=x=0$ then

$$x_1=0,\ x_2=-\frac53, \ x_3=3.$$

Substituting theses values back to the original equation represented by the first augmented matrix we get

$$0-3\frac53+4\cdot3=-5+12=7$$
and

$$0-9\cdot\frac53+7\cdot 3=-15+21=6$$

as it has to be.

Comment: But how do you know know its, 5/3 and 0? -8 and 1 work as well.

Comment: For any $u$ there is a triplet of solutions: $$x_1=u; \ x_2=-\frac{5+u}3; \ x_3=3.$$